# Not able to add list<String> BCC to setBccAddresses ,VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [885 line] common.apex.runtime.impl.ScalarList@3fc50cb5

Tags: apex, list, singleemailmessage

FYI .........If I remove this BCC code emails are going fine.

[image]

```
enter code here       
    public static List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> listEmailMessage = new  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

 List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

 for(string s : applicationMap.keySet()){
        for(string emailString :AppConUserMap.get(s) ){ //preparing email for 1 contact 
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setTargetObjectId(emailString);//we are passing contact id here 
            mail.setWhatId(s);
            mail.setTemplateId(tpl.Id);
            if(isBccReq == true){ // changes by shashank for PLIFE-32082
                List<String> listBcc = new List<String>{};
                listBcc = (mapAppIdAccId.containsKey(s) ? mapAccIdListBCCEmails.get(mapAppIdAccId.get(s)) : NULL );
                String [] emailsAsArray = listBcc;
                System.debug('listBcc'+listBcc);
                for (String  var : listBcc) {
                    System.debug('var'+var);
                }
                mail.setBccAddresses( listBcc);  //                  
            }
          
            mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owdid);
            mails.add(mail);
            listEmailMessage.add(mail);
            applicationIds.add(s);
        }
    }


        List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail( listEmailMessage,false ); // ## changed FinalMails
        for(integer i=0; i<results.size(); i++){
            if(results[i].Success){
                //readytoUpdate.add(indexWhatIdMap.containsKey(i)?indexWhatIdMap.get(i):''); 
                readytoUpdate.add(indexWhatIdMap.get(i)); 
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code you have on the server is **not** the code you have in VS Code; the line of code that reads `if(results[i].Success) {` should be `if(results[i].isSuccess()) {`, so the code fails to compile and deploy to the server. The error itself comes from the way you're checking if you should set the BCC list. You cannot set a `null` value to the BCC list.

```
List<String> listBcc = new List<String>{};
listBcc = (mapAppIdAccId.containsKey(s) ? mapAccIdListBCCEmails.get(mapAppIdAccId.get(s)) : NULL );
String [] emailsAsArray = listBcc;
System.debug('listBcc'+listBcc);
// NOTE: This would actually be a NullPointerException
for (String  var : listBcc) {
    System.debug('var'+var);
}
// NOTE: listBcc may be null here
mail.setBccAddresses( listBcc);  //
```

Instead, you'll want to just check:

```
List<String> listBcc = mapAppIdAccId.get(s);
if(listBcc != null && listBcc.size() > 0) {
  mail.setBccAddresses(listBcc);
}
```

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox i made changes as you mentioned but i am facing that scalarList issues now also.